# When someone can call out the bidder out rule?

Tags: pinochle

I play dbl deck pinochle once a week with the same 3 friends and was introduced to the *bidder out rule* which I never played in all my 60 years of playing.

**bidder out rule:** if both teams go over the amount it takes to win (usually 500) in the same round, the bidder wins regardless of the opponents higher score.

When does one put the rule into effect? For example, if the score is 260 to 215, should someone be calling out that rule?

Comment: _someone will call out this rule before either team has reached the winning score_ what do you mean by "call out"? Just remind people of a potentially relevant rule? Or try to (mis-) use the rule?

Comment: The rule is always in effect. It doesn't get put into effect at some point in the game. You don't need to call it to have it be in effect.

Comment: To be honest a lot of bidding games where one player/team wins the bid have a rule where the bidder wins if multiple people/team go over the winning score on the same hand. I also find it not uncommon that you need to have the bid (or set the bidder) in order to win and you can be above the winning score and not win.

Answer (score -1):

The rule is always in effect for single or double deck. We generally say “bidder goes out” as a reminder but it isn’t required.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).